# UnboundLocalError, can't modify the parameter "where it is not associated with a value", while it's associated with its default value

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scoping

i'd checked some other similar questions trying to find out what's wrong with this but they didn't help a lot as i needed to change the value in the function **myself** which i don't want to, and i want the user to be able to do that.

Here's the code:

```
import threading

def showColor(color = "Green"):
    class loading(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        def run():
            c = '>'+color+'<'
            print(c)
showColor("Red")
```

I REALLY have no idea why is this happening... i know it's definitely because of that *global, local* thing but i still can't fix it if i don't give it a value right inside of the function itself too...
traceback:

```
cannot access local variable 'color' where it is not associated with a value
```

But... i mean it is associated with a value right? how can i fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. What version of Python are you running? I don't think this is version-specific, but just want to make sure. I tried 3.8-3.11. Please make a [mre]. Maybe there's some context missing.

Comment: Oh, and that's not a traceback; the traceback is above that line. Please post the [full error text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: i'm using `Python 3.11.2`(exactly this version), OH! i forgot one more part of the code!!! i'm gonna edit the question now AND i found out the problem is ACTUALLY from that! but still don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: I FIXED IT! sorry idk how the hell i never paid attention XD why am i keep being so careless?! anyways i'll answer to it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the class should NOT be inside the function and must be defined outside of it and INSTEAD be CALLED inside the function.

*don't know how i didn't notice that i could do this instead*

So it'll be like this:

```
import threading

class loading(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(color):
        c = '>'+color+'<'
        print(c)

def showColor(color="Green"):
    loading.run(color)

showColor("Red")
```